# android studio cannot resolve import org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android, json, gradle, libgdx, libraries

I used libgdx to build my project and I am having issues using the **JSONObject** class. When I add `import org.json.JSONObject`, it says it cannot resolve. How do I add that library to my project?

Here is what I have tried without success:

1. I downloaded the `json-simple-1.1.jar` and put it in core/build/libs folder. Could not use `import.org.json.simple.JSONObject` either.
2. When browsing the tree in Android Studio as "Packages" dropdown, I can see the classes I want under `"Core -> Libraries -> org -> json"` but I cannot add them to my project. I get a "cannot refractor, class is in a jar file" error.

Is there something I have not tried yet to solve this issue? I feel I will run into this again as I try to use other external libraries.

Thank you.

Comment: Let' hope you are using Android Studio and the libGdx gradle version(latest). Add the repo in the top most `build.gradle`, http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20141113.

Comment: This worked, thanks!
I added: compile 'org.json:json:20141113' to the "core" dependencies in my build.gradle file.

Comment: in libgdx there is also in com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json utility class to avoid import another dependencies

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using LibGdx, it does not come with a Gradle setup, making multi-project builds streamlined.

You need to add `implementation 'org.json:json:<version>'` to the dependencies block of your top-level `build.gradle`.

To find the latest version, see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/

For example, using the latest version at the time of writing:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.json:json:20200518'
}
```

Comment: Please note that this might not be implementation intended as this library may only be used for good - see https://wiki.debian.org/qa.debian.org/jsonevil