# I can´t import JSON library into Android Studio

Tags: android, json

I was reading on this web people with the same error : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588802/android-studio-cannot-resolve-import-org-json-jsonobject), I had synchronized my project and right now I was looking for more information but I don´t get anything.

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
   compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
   compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
}
```

Android Studio autocomplete my import but it doesn´t work. I think this is the last repository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

[image: Example]

Please, any help will be grateful.

Comment: What's the specific problem? What should you be seeing that you're not?

Comment: I can't create an object of JSONObject, is like I didn´t import the library. I imported the .jar and I have the same project, when I try to create a JSON object I get an error. "Cannot resolve symbol JSONObject", but I imported the library.

Comment: At runtime? That'd be good to know. In which gradle file did you put the dependency?

Comment: When do you see that error?

Comment: I have added the dependency to the build.grandle, with other libraries (with APP Compat or Facebook API) , I see the error when I write "import org.json.JSONObject", When I write "import.org" Android Studio shows me the API json with JSONObject, I can select it, however, when I do it Androids Studio shows me the error "cannot resolve symbol JSONObject",

I have spent all day reading other threads of people with the same error, but they resolve it importing the library and I already done this.